# How to format JSON without square brackets

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

This should be easy so what am I missing?

I'm needing to have claims generated in a JSON body for a subsequent REST API call to a service. I don't see a way to prevent GenerateJSON from including square brackets when there is a entity name at the top. The REST API service is choking on them.

**Needing:**

```
{"CustomerEntity":  
  {  
    "ExternalIdentityId": "9988875",  
    "FirstName":"David",  
    "LastName":"Longfellow"  
  }  
}
```

**Getting:**

```
{"CustomerEntity": [  
  {  
    "ExternalIdentityId": "9988875",  
    "FirstName":"David",  
    "LastName":"Longfellow"  
  }  
  ]  
}
```

Comment: Include your claims transformation code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following format (without the "0" before the second notation).

```
<ClaimsTransformations>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="CustomerEntity.ExternalIdentityId" DataType="string" Value="9988875"/>
      <InputParameter Id="CustomerEntity.FirstName" DataType="string" Value="David"/>
      <InputParameter Id="CustomerEntity.LastName" DataType="string" Value="Longfellow"/>
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="requestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

Output:

```json
{
   "CustomerEntity":{
      "ExternalIdentityId":"9988875",
      "FirstName":"David",
      "LastName":"Longfellow"
   }
}
```

### Sample 2

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="customerEntity.email" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" TransformationClaimType="customerEntity.userObjectId" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="customerEntity.firstName" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" TransformationClaimType="customerEntity.lastName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="customerEntity.role.name" DataType="string" Value="Administrator"/>
    <InputParameter Id="customerEntity.role.id" DataType="long" Value="1"/>
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="requestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Output:

```json
 {
    "customerEntity":{
       "email":"john.s@contoso.com",
       "userObjectId":"31ee61cf-521f-4132-8e19-11a3b6562666",
       "firstName":"John",
       "lastName":"Smith",
       "role":{
          "name":"Administrator",
          "id": 1
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That was the trick. Include the dot but not any number behind it.

Comment: Glad to hear Robert. I have updated the doc with your sample (similar). For the official doc, please see the [second sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#example-2).